# How should I start with OAuth server at PHP

Tags: php, oauth

Have found the following example of OAuth server
http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/OAuth_TestServer.php

But it is unclear for me 
1. How I should generate certificates

2. How I should specify access token/access token secret/request token/request token secret, 
   should they stored in database? Should it regenerated for each request? What else I should store in database?
3. Where should I implement the verification of Access token?

Please advice

Comment: Here is the list of how should start with OAuth

http://www.slideshare.net/lucamea/integrating-services-with-oauth-presentation
http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/OAuth_TestServer.php
http://code.google.com/intl/ru/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html
http://term.ie/oauth/example/index.php
http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/wiki/ServerHowTo 
http://oauth-sandbox.mediamatic.nl/
http://www.hueniverse.com/hueniverse/2008/10/beginners-gui-1.html

Comment: Its frustrating when people don't mark any answers

Comment: You should have posted that as an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 3):

To Generate Certificates, you need to create a CSR (Certificate Signing Request)

If you have access to cPanel, then you can generate a CSR easily. If you don't then you will need to download some software to generate a CSR.

After you have your CSR, you can head over to [CACert](http://cacert.org) for a free certificate. However, be warned: not all modern browsers trust CACert, so you might get warnings. If you don't want this, you will have to pay for a certificate from a professional provider, like VeriSign.